Apps Script Hourly Clear and Refresh help needed
I'm brand new to trying to code through app scripts and I've made something that seems to mostly do what I need it to, however it will run but sometimes do a ton of Failed triggers.  My goal is to have this Google Sheet clear itself every hour, and then pull from a Google Drive folder that will have a file placed in it by later connecting the Google Drive to an FTP client.
I've spent a few weeks on this and it seems to do well "mostly" but I would to get it completed and closed up.  This community has been super helpful getting me this far as I lurked and learned.  Any advice on how to get this finished would be helpful.
The goal is to completely clear the sheet, and then import the file once every hour. If it can be done on the clock, that would be great but not necessary. I haven't looked at that coding yet, so far (I think) it should run every 2 hours as I have it set up now.
The top row that is missing is
const FOLDER_ID - "Link to the google folder where the imported file is", this works 100%
Numerous versions and searches to find something that reliably works.  I've never used this before so I'm mostly copying what I find.
const FOLDER_ID = "link to the folder on google drive"

// run the two functions below as the MAIN command
function Main() {
  clearTheSheet();
  ImportCSV();
}
//clear the entire sheet before uploading new folder
function clearTheSheet() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.getRange("A2:T99999").clearContent();

//one second delay
  Utilities.sleep(6000);}

//import the entire csv file from google drive and then delete the file
function ImportCSV() {
  Utilities.sleep(6000);

  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID) ;
  let files = folder.getFiles() ;
  let data = [];

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    let fileType = file.getMimeType();
    if (fileType == "text/csv") {
        let csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
        csvData.splice(0,1);
        csvData = csvData.filter(x => x[0] != '');
        csvData.forEach(x => data.push(x));
        file.setTrashed(true);
    }
  }

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("NAME OF TAB");
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()).sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
}


Questions that are of the form "please help me finish this" tend to be closed here for being too vague. Please pick one problem from your snags list, and amend the question text to focus on that one thing. If you have to do some debugging to specify what that thing is, that's OK.

Additionally to what was mentioned in the previous comment, questions on this site should not include chitchat, ref. http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior. I.E. The post should be focused only on describing a specific problem that is unique to programming.

You can simplify the code with method chaining, like this:
function test() {
  importCsvFiles_(FOLDER_ID, 'NAME OF TAB');
}

function importCsvFiles_(folderId, sheetName) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!sheet) throw new Error(`Cannot find sheet '${sheetName}'.`);
  if (!sheet.getFrozenRows()) sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  sheet.getDataRange().offset(1, 0).clearContent();
  const files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    if (file.getMimeType() === 'text/csv') {
      const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString())
        .slice(1)
        .filter(row => row.join(''));
      appendRows_(sheet, csvData);
      file.setTrashed(true);
    }
  }
  sheet.sort(3);
}

For that to work, you will need to paste the appendRows_() and getLastRow_() utility functions in your script project as well. You can get those functions from How to append data to a certain column?
To run the routine periodically, add a time-driven trigger that executes the test() function.
